# Is it reasonable to expect a programmer to delete an object after an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a class structured like this:

```
class Server
{
    private:
    SOCKET listener;

    public:
    Server(char const * const address, unsigned short int port);
    ~Server();
    void Start();
};
```

Is there an alternative to relying on the user of the library to `delete` the object if the `Start` method throws an exception during say a call to `CreateIoCompletionPort` or `listen`?

A little bit subjective I know, but is there a best practice for this kind of situation?

I wanted to avoid duplicating the cleanup code and potentially causing problems with double freeing resources and the added complexity of also having to track what is cleaned up and what is not.

**EDIT**

To clear up some of the questions asked, I am referring to when a user of my code will create an instance of the `Server` class. I am trying to decide whether or not I should go the route of protecting the class from executing when it's in an invalid state due to an exception being encountered within `Start`. If the `Start` method fails because of some issue, then it's an unrecoverable error and the class is in a bad state and cannot go any further. This would be something like a configuration error or a system level error that prevents `Start` from succeeding, but at the same time leaves the `SOCKET` in a state that can't be reverted without closing and creating a new socket.

Comment: That'd be non-exception safe code and is bad practice.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what object you're relying on the user to `delete`. Is it an instance of `Server`? If so, then it's up to the user to make sure he doesn't leak the object in case of an exception, and he should be using a smart pointer to hold the `Server` instance (assuming he needs to dynamically allocate it in the first place).

Comment: I know it's probably not what you want to do but you don't have to duplicate any code; just add a `Cleanup()` method (it doesn't even have to be `public`) and have your fields be `NULL` initially so you can check if they were set.

Comment: If you are talking about an instance of `Server`, yes you should expect that if someone `new`'s it then they should `delete` it.  If you're talking about your code `new`ing a `listener` or something then it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely unreasonable to expect a programmer to remember deleting everything he allocates, especially in the presence of exceptions: there is a limit to how much a human being can keep in mind, and in a sufficiently large system you run against that limit pretty quickly.

However, deleting everything is what he must do in order to avoid memory leaks. To achieve any degree of success, programmers need to do two things:

- **Follow defensive coding practices** - Prefer objects allocated in automated store to pointers. Use smart pointers when you must allocate objects dynamically. Adhere to [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) techniques.
- **Write exhaustive unit tests, and profile them for memory leaks** - Using memory profiler helps you spot leaks that are otherwise hard to find.

The first part is prevention; the second part is the "safety net". If you are disciplined about using smart pointers and running your unit tests, your code would be [exception-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) at the basic level (i.e. it would provide a leak-free guarantee). You could go a step further, do your allocations upfront, and change state only when all allocations have succeeded to implement transactional semantic for strong exception safety.

Comment: Add something about "exception safety" and I'll mark this as the answer. Basically, that's what I was looking for and you helped me locate the answer I needed. It seems like I was writing code that is not exception safe because the object state becomes invalid when it encounters and error. Calling the same function twice in my application to re-attempt `Start` would cause unpredictable behavior.